# Google Chrome cannot read and write to its data directory : selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[Here's the issue i am facing now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htAWu.jpg)

I could launch chrome driver. However my selenium code suddenly doesnt work and pops up above image.

Hope someone can shed light as i couldn't find a solution online. .

Comment: I am experiencing this issue too.  It started when I updated chrome to version 90.  So it's either an issue introduced with version 90 of chrome, or the corresponding version of chromedriver.

Answer (score 11):

Generally BarthRid's answer is correct, providing full path to userdata folder works with Chrome 90+. But if you store userdata folder in the same directory as your script, you can use pathlib to manage things more easily.

```
import pathlib

script_directory = pathlib.Path().absolute()

options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={script_directory}\\userdata")
```

This way allows you to store actual script's directory in a variable, and via formatted string put it in selenium's options argument. Useful while dealing with multiple instances.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem to yours and @scott degen.
[options.add_argument line of your pasted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VqJq.png)

I changed mine from:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
```

to the full directory, and it seems to be working better now.

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\environments\selenium")
```

Comment: I've downloaded the latest ChromeDriver and changed the directory to 

options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\environments\selenium")

It works now! Thank you!!!

Comment: You actually need to escape those "\" or it would not work at all for me.
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\environments\\selenium")

Answer (score 4):

I changed mine from:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
```

to the full directory, and it seems to be working better now.

```
dir_path = os.getcwd()
chrome_option.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={dir_path}/selenium')
```

Comment: Great! answer! can also be 

```chrome_option.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={os.path.join(dir_path,"selenium")}')```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Chrome changes its Current Working Directory during startup and so the relative path won't work. You can try to convert the user-data-dir to absolute path then pass to chrome. See [Bug: 1058347](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/1ce826cbd717bb5ff45b574011d17121b76b2613)